# alinhamento a direita(right), com as divs uma abaixo da outra!

Tags: css

em uma pagina quero colocar um texto a esquerda e quatro divs a direita, cada div sera formatada para ficar visivel em formato quadrado e dentro de cada uma div terá pequenos textos com alguns icones. Muito bem, o texto ja esta a esquerda e as divs ja estao a direita como na imagem abaixo, o unico problema é que eu quero que elas fiquem uma embaixo da outra na vertical, mas quando eu dei o float, elas se alinharam na horizontal, ja tentei algumas coisas que achei aqui e em outros cantos da internet, porem nao obtive sucesso em fazer o que quero. abaixo da imagem, segue o codigo html e css da pagina.
[image: ja esta quase como quero, so falta coloca-las uma abaixo da outra]

```
<section id="quem">
            <br>
            <div id="boxqtab">
                <div class="qtab">
                </div>
                <div class="qtab">
                </div>
                <div class="qtab">
                </div>
                <div class="qtab">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tquem">
                <p id="pquemtitulo">Quem Somos Nós</p>
                <br>
                <p id="pquem">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
            </div>
            <!--<a href="#quem"><button  id="qbutton">Proxima Pagina</button></a>-->
        </section>


#quem {
    background-color: #6A5ACD;
    color: white;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
#tquem {

}
.qtab {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
}
/*#qbutton {
   background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer; 
    margin-left: 50px;*/
```

Comment: Tente colocar essas divs dentro de outra e alinhá-la à direita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem várias formas de resolver isso. Pra mim a mais simples é a que eu vou postar abaixo.

Basicamente tirei o float das div's internas e passei para a div "boxqtab" e limitei o tamanho dessa div para o mesmo tamanho das div "qtab" forçando elas a ficarem uma abaixo da outra.

```
#boxqtab{
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}

.qtab {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: agradeço muito irmao, ajudou demais, inclusive vai ajudar em outras coisas no mesmo layout... resolveu...